# Visual Studio C++ . error msb 4014 .using a mac with parallels and windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, msbuild, parallels

Who can help? Mac - Parallels - Visual Studio - C++

I use Parallels on my Mac Book in combination with Windows 7. This works fine. Now I installed Visual Studio an create a simple c++ "Hello-World-Program".
When I start the programm the following error message appears:

```
1>\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test1\test1\test1.vcxproj : error MSB4014: Der Buildvorgang wurde aufgrund eines internen Fehlers unerwartet beende...t.
1>\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test1\test1\test1.vcxproj : error MSB4014: Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.BuildAbortedException: Der Buildvorgang wurde abgebrochen. "MSBuild.exe" konnte nicht als untergeordneter Knoten gestartet werden, da die Datei nicht am Speicherort "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" gefunden wurde. Geben Sie den korrekten Speicherort ggf. in den BuildParameters oder mit der MSBUILD_EXE_PATH-Umgebungsvariable an.
1>\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test1\test1\test1.vcxproj : error MSB4014: bei Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.AttemptCreateNode(INodeProvider nodeProvider, NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration)
```

I googled about it and found a hotfix from microsoft support. But the link does not work anymore.
Who can help me please?

Comment: you tried "http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2298853"?

Comment: ich checked the link: "Oops! The page you are looking for may have a new location, or is no longer available."

Comment: remove the " from the link.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2298853

Comment: the link of the hotfix doesn't work either :-(

Comment: use this link to request the fix via email: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hotfix/kbhotfix?kbnum=2298853&kbln=en-us